# how to split a monorepo accross multiple teams each has access to only a slice of repo?

Tags: git, github, gitlab, microservices, project-management

there are a lot of good advantages in monorepo, we also read that large companies like google and facebook use this tech to keep all source code in single repo.

but question is how do you manage to limit access of a certain team to projects he is working on only in monorepo ?

example we have a microservice infrastructure

service A
service B
Api Gateway
service A here is developer using Team A, and service B is developed by different team (team b) while Api Gateway is common repo in this project.

now how can we limit access of each team to his own service only ?

also since a monorepo can be Gigabytes in size, so we need teams to only clone parts that they care about, not whole project

currently we keep every part in its own repo, and this way we can controll access control for each team, but i was asked to migrate this to monorepo and im not sure how to protect source code and split project in such approach.

thank you

Answer (score 0):

> since a monorepo can be Gigabytes in size, so we need teams to only clone parts that they care about, not whole project

for this you should check the partial a.k.a narrow clone feature which is pretty bleeding edge. I'm not sure if any service currently supports it but if you have own server you probably can sei it up there yourself. See https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/Documentation/technical/partial-clone.txt

In theory, it could also enable access control - you can fail the fetch request if users asks for a blob it should not have access to. Probably it would require some additional hacking.

otherwise, git does not have the reading access control